# Fast image stream using objective C

Tags: objective-c, image, networking, streaming, bonjour

I've been working on a project which involves a network connection between a server on a Mac, and a client on an iOS device.
The client side requires a live view of of the server's screen.

As of now, my solution has been

- getting snapshots of the Mac's screen using CGDisplayCreateImage( ). Timing is done with an NSTimer set to fire every 1/30.0 second.
- compressing and generating GIF images using CGImageDestination
- sending the GIF images (which are stored in NSData) over Bonjour to the client.
- client receives the data, and initializes a new UIImage from it, passing it into an image view.

But I've been encountering a few problems with this method.

1. The latency is horrible. Each image took many seconds to load, and seemed to never even reach the client.
2. Each image NSData object's size was around 170000 bytes long. This seems WAY too high to even send over network fast enough. But I have no idea how to compress the images further.

Thank you.

Comment: .gif isnt exactly a good format for what essentially should be a video stream... maybe look into turning your servers screenshots into some kind of video stream format and go from there

Comment: GIF was chosen because I couldn't find a format smaller than it by using CGImageDestination.

But thanks for the comment. Any idea where I can start on the "video stream from screenshots" part?  I currently have no idea how to work on videos and such, and that's why I opted for this image sending thing here. :/

Comment: The problem with compression is that consecutive images will differ only in a small way. compressing each image with gif cannot take any advantage of it

Comment: @switt unfortunately im quite clueless when it comes to video streaming so i cant help with that, but ye all i know is gif has terrible compression compared to video streams so its probably a bad foundation to what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad So that's the advantage of using video streams. Any ideas where I can start? It's all very vague for me right now since I know next to nothing about mpeg encoding or video streaming.

Comment: I would say: "AVFoundation."

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad  I've come across the RTSP protocol. Would it be more suitable for this job? Also, would using AVFoundation still be compatible with it?

Comment: For this project, I'll need a latency as low as possible, 100 milliseconds at most, I guess.

Comment: AVFoundation is for generating a compressed movie file. This has nothing to do with the protocol for transport. But I do not have experience with that.